# Asterisk Realtime pattern matching

Tags: odbc, asterisk

I'm using the realtime db lookup feature to generate my extensions.conf

This works fine if I specify a complete number in the exten field, however if I try and use a pattern _0. for example it doesn't work. (Gives an error that the extension isn't found)

If I use that pattern directly in extensions.conf though it works fine.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You probably need read this

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+RealTime+Extensions

You need also consider this

> ; While most dynamic realtime engines are automatically used when
>   defined in ; this file, 'extensions', distinctively, is not.  To
>   activate dynamic realtime ; extensions, you must turn them on in each
>   respective context within ; extensions.conf with a switch statement. 
>   The syntax is: ;      switch =>
>   Realtime/[[db_context@]tablename]/ ; The only option available
>   currently is the 'p' option, which disallows ; extension pattern
>   queries to the database.  If you have no patterns defined ; in a
>   particular context, this will save quite a bit of CPU time.  However,
>   ; note that using dynamic realtime extensions **is not recommended
>   anymore** as a ; best practice; instead, you should consider writing a
>   static dialplan with ; proper data abstraction via a tool like
>   func_odbc.